# How to clone/copy a list of objects that may be views?

Tags: view, clone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is a Snowflake question about creating views.

We need to recreate a list of objects in a target database from a source. Some of them are tables, some of them are views. Many may already exist in the target, and must be dropped first.

For all-tables, cloning is working without issues:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TO_DB.X CLONE FROM_DB.X;
```

However some of the objects are views, and this causes an error and potentially(?) another problem:

1) Error:  Object 'X' already exists as VIEW
 2) If it doesn't exist: View will get created as Table

So we need to make sure that Views get created as VIEWS not as a table.
How to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% following your question.  If you are trying to clone views, you can't specifically clone a view.  A view is only cloned if the schema or database is cloned (views would then be cloned as child objects in those clones).

If you are trying recreate a view from the from_db to the to_db, I'd recommend using the `get_ddl()` function against the "from" schema/database, and then executing the result of that in the "to" schema/database.

Is that the issue you are asking about?

Views will not be created as tables unless you explicitly do a CTAS from a view to a table.  It won't happen during a CLONE operation.

Comment: thanks - yes, essentially I need the view to arrive in the target database - it doesn't need to be a clone-operation. Thanks for providing the function.